# Cambiar de color diferentes elementos de una imagen svg

Tags: javascript, css, html5, svg

Quiero trabajar los elementos de un archivo .svg tales como el de < circle > que se observa en el código; pero de qué manera lo puedo hacer con javascript alguna idea u orientación?¿, Saludos a todos :)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Generator: Adobe Illustrator 19.2.0, SVG Export Plug-In . SVG Version: 6.00 Build 0)  -->
 <svg version="1.1" id="Capa_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 489.3 14.2" style="enable-background:new 0 0 489.3 14.2;" xml:space="preserve">
 <style type="text/css">
   .st0{fill:#FFFFFF;}
   .st1{opacity:0.55;fill:#636363;}
 </style>
 <g>
   <circle id="Circle1" class="st0" cx="9.4" cy="7.1" r="6.5"/>
   <circle id="Circle2" class="st1" cx="104.1" cy="7.1" r="6.5"/>
   <circle id="Circle3" class="st1" cx="198.7" cy="7.1" r="6.5"/>
   <circle id="Circle4" class="st1" cx="293.4" cy="7.1" r="6.5"/>
   <circle id="Circle5" class="st1" cx="388.1" cy="7.1" r="6.5"/>
   <circle id="Circle6" class="st1" cx="482.8" cy="7.1" r="6.5"/>
</g>
</svg>
```

Comment: Si me gustaría cambiarlos dinámicamente :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Primero hay que tener en cuenta que **NO** puedes trabajar directamente `javascript` en un `.svg` necesitas utilizar `svg` dentro de un `html`.

Para cambiar los colores dinámicamente dentro del `svg` te recomiendo utilizar `Jquery` con la función `.css()` utilizando el atributo `fill` para el color, puedes cambiarlo en un evento `on click()` o en un loop, pero dependerá de lo que necesites, te muestro un ejemplo utilizando un loop:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<svg version="1.1" id="Capa_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 489.3 14.2" style="enable-background:new 0 0 489.3 14.2;" xml:space="preserve">
<g>
<circle id="Circle1" class="st0" cx="9.4" cy="7.1" r="6.5"/>
<circle id="Circle2" class="st1" cx="104.1" cy="7.1" r="6.5"/>
<circle id="Circle3" class="st1" cx="198.7" cy="7.1" r="6.5"/>
<circle id="Circle4" class="st1" cx="293.4" cy="7.1" r="6.5"/>
<circle id="Circle5" class="st1" cx="388.1" cy="7.1" r="6.5"/>
<circle id="Circle6" class="st1" cx="482.8" cy="7.1" r="6.5"/>
</g>
</svg>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
CambiarColor();
var i = 0;

function CambiarColor() {
   setTimeout(CambiarColor,3000);
   var color = ["red","blue","yellow","green"];
   $("#Circle1").css("fill", color[i]);
   $("#Circle2").css("fill", color[i]);
   $("#Circle3").css("fill", color[i]);
   $("#Circle4").css("fill", color[i]);
   $("#Circle5").css("fill", color[i]);
   $("#Circle6").css("fill", color[i]);
   i++;
   if(i==color.length) i=0;
}
});
</script>
```

Comment: En eso tienes razón @iuninefrendor, y no niego que la respuesta sea mala por el contrario está bien, solo que yo manejo el .svg como un < object > de esta forma:

         <object id="dots" type="image/svg+xml" data="img/points.svg" style="width: 50vw; height: auto;">
              </object>